# Java regex how to match _, /, or /123?

Tags: java, regex

I have prepared this REGEX `[_[/\\\d+]]` to get either of below

- An underscore -> `_`

OR

- A forward slash followed by some numbers `/123`

So when I try to match below are the results

1. `_` (Matches -> OK)
2. `/` (Matches -> OK)
3. `/123` (Doesn't match -> Not OK)

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `[` and `]` which denotes a character class which will match any of the listed a single time. Using `\d+` will match either a digit or a `+` char.

If you add a quantifier like `+` to the character class itself you will repeat any of the listed but you will not have the OR logic.

You should use a pipe `|` for the OR part which will match either an underscore OR a forward slash followed by 1+ digits.

To also match a single forward slash you could match 0+ digits using the `*` instead of `+`

```
_|/\d+
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B8tgA5/1)

**Note** to double escape the backslash in Java `_|/\\d+`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the online tool.

Well actually I'm trying something more bigger than this. Now I'm trying to do the below leveraging the OR operator but it looks like I'm not able to figure our how to group a piece of expression i.e. the LHS and RHS of the OR operator within a regular expression. Take for example _|(/\\d+_)\\d+

Here I want to achieve 
1) _123 (Not Working)
OR
2) /123_123 (Working)

It looks like the OR operator is considering the whole part i.e. (/\\d+_)\\d+ as RHS. How can I provide (/\\d+_)\\d+ as only the Right Hand Side of the OR operator ?

Comment: @SubhajitRoy I am not sure if this is valid syntax `|(/\d+)\d+` because there is nothing on the left side of the pipe. If you want to match either `123` or `/123_123` you could use `\d+|/\d+_\d+` See for example https://regex101.com/r/fekLup/1 Or you could also use a non capturing group `(?:\d+|/\d+_\d+)` See https://regex101.com/r/3CIjYl/1

Answer (score 2):

Use: `_|\\d*`

**Explanation:**

```
  _     # an underscore
|       # OR
  /     # a slash
  \\d*  # 0 or more digits
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the pattern: `_|/\\d*`

The `|` essentially combines two separate patterns into one, and will match if either side matches.

This will match:

- `_`
- `/`
- `/1`
- `/12`
- `/123`
  etc.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right your question you want either:

- one underscore
- or a slash followed by one or more digits

Here my solution:

`_|(/\\d+)`

Meaning:

- `_` : underscore
- `|` : or
- `(` : beginning of capturing group
- `\\d`: digit
- `+` : one or more times
- `)` : endof capturing group

Hope this helps!